# Do not load images in javascript

Tags: javascript

I build a website and i want to ask the user when each time visit the site, if he want to display images or not. and if not, i want to do not load them and display the page without any img tag

i tried this, but this is not useful because the page will be loaded

```
function load_img () {
if (!confirm("Do you want to load the images on your site?")) {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var l = images.length;
    for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
    }
}
}
```

i need some code that don't load any img tag when the page load,
and not a code that hide or remove the images after the page is loaded and the images are displayed

can someone help me please with this javascript code

thank you

Comment: Help or do for you? what have you tried so far?

Comment: i did the following code, but this code is after loading the page and this is what i dont want:

window.onload = load_img;

function load_img () {
 if (!confirm("Do you want to load the images on your site?")) {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var l = images.length;
  for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
   images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
  }
 }
}

Comment: It's better to edit your question then to write a comment, because of code formatting.

Comment: ok i did if you want check my post

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). What this plugin does is load the image when the image is on the visible area of the page.

Their idea is to put the original URL to the image in `data-original` attribute and in the `src` attribute put some small image e.g. 1x1 transparent gif like this:

```
<img data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/grey.gif” />
```

and then you are able to load all the images whenever you want to just by replacing the the `src`.

this is a simple javascript code that you can try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if( confirm('Images?') ) {
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(i in img) {
            var original = img[i].getAttribute('data-original');
            if( original.length ) {
                img[i].setAttribute('src', original);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not useful for me since i need a code that do not load any image when the page load and not when the page finish loading

Comment: @ElieHaber I think this is useful for you because he does not load anything but a dummy image grey.gif until you click the confirm. But this does not work for background images but that could be added manually if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try jquery : $("img").remove();

Comment: this will still load the images and remove them after they are loaded, but i want to not load them from the beginning

Comment: If an image has display:none style, it will not load. You could add that style to them before if you want to remove them, then apply jQuery for remove.

Comment: yes, but all that will occur after the page has loaded with the images and that what i don't want, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to solve this problem from the server side!

Make start page with a link to a version of the page with images and one without the images. You can write a server side script (PHP?) to show or hide the images. Simple removing the images could break the page design. Also removing html image tags does not do the trick. What about background images, some in css files, ...

If you like to do this an on the client side with javascript you have to remove all images and add them manually with javascript.

Comment: thank you, i find this very useful since i use php for programming on the srver side, i will try this

Comment: PiTheNumber, i think that solving this problem is better on the client side, because many requests for the page in the same time make the server handle all that in one time and slowing him, but on the client side, each client will process his code on his side. not true?

Comment: Do you have performance problems? If you have performance problems I don't think it will be caused by this. We are talking about loading one static page with nearly no content. You better handle performance problems if they appear.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
if (confirm('Hide images?'))
{
    $('img').remove();
}
```

Without jQuery you have to use getElemtentsByTag and a loop.

Comment: ok but i want to do not display the images from the beginning, i mean that when the user is promted, the page is not loaded yet and the html code is empty

Comment: This will still load the images despite they'll be removed after the user confirms.

Comment: i did this using:

window.onload = load_img;

function load_img () {
 if (!confirm("Do you want to load the images on your site?")) {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var l = images.length;
  for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
   images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
  }
 }
}

Comment: but this is not useful since i want to not load them from the beginning

Comment: lazy question => lazy answer. If it does not work for you, your internet connection is to fast and it makes no sense to not load the images ;) Anyway, it would be better to solve this problem from the server side. But I make a new answer for that...